# How do I print start and end of function with verbose, Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, debugging, printing, verbose

I've written a nice chunk of code, and I'm looking to improve my verbose output. I had the idea of an `if verbose: print '**** function_name ****'` at the start and end of the function and even defined a function to make it easier to call (I'm using the very sexy verbose print written by kindall [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5980042/how-to-implement-the-verbose-or-v-option-into-a-script))

```
def verbwrap(function, side):
    if side=='start':
        verboseprint(' ******  %s  ******' %(function))
    if side=='end': 
        verboseprint(' ^^^^^^  %s  ^^^^^^' %(function))
```

with the intention of using it like this:

```
import inspect

def test(lst):
    verbwrap(inspect.currentframe().f_code.co_name,'start')
    for i in lst:
        print i
    verbwrap('test', 'end') #equivalent to above, but easier to write :(
```

Is there a way for me to only call a re-worked `verbwrap()` once? No amount of tinkering has led me to the answer!

Comment: What do you mean by "call a re-worked `verbwrap()` once"?

Comment: sorry, I mean is there an alternative to my `verbwrap()` that would only need to be called once inside `test()` to print at the start and end of the function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Considering you want to print something only at the start and end of the function then the best way to do this is to use a decorator.

```
def verbwrap(function):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        verboseprint(' ******  %s  ******' %(function.__name__))
        result = function(*args, **kwargs)
        verboseprint(' ^^^^^^  %s  ^^^^^^' %(function.__name__))
        return result
    return wrapper
```

Now use the above decorator with any function you want to debug:

```
@verbwrap
def test(lst):
    for i in lst:
        print i
```

**Demo:**

When `verbose` is `True`:

```
 ******  test  ******
1
2
3
 ^^^^^^  test  ^^^^^^
```

When `verbose` is `False`:

```
1
2
3
```

---

You can make this even more dynamic by calculating the value of `verbose` inside the `wrapper` function, using this approach you can decide to debug or not to debug when the function is actually invoked.

```
def verbwrap(function):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        # Calculate the value of `verbose` here.
        # Say you're reading it from a config etc
        verbose = False
        if verbose:
            print ' ******  %s  ******' %(function.__name__)
            result = function(*args, **kwargs)
            print ' ^^^^^^  %s  ^^^^^^' %(function.__name__)
            return result
        else:
            return function(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper
```

Comment: Wow, this is amazing! I didn't know about decorators, this is really tidy. Thanks.